# Determine an Integral..

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let

$ B:= \{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 | 1 \leq z \leq 3, x^2+ y^2 \leq 16 \} $

I want to determine

$ \int_B \frac{z}{cosh^2 \sqrt{x^2+y^2}} d(x,y,z) $

I know it is a cylinder with radius 4.

I tried transforming with polarcoordinates-that was just not helpful. Can you give me some pretty hints how I finally this integral :-)? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think polar coordinates do work here:

$$\int_B \frac{z}{\cosh^2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dx\,dy\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}\!\int_0^4\!\int_1^3\frac{z r}{\cosh^2 r}dz\,dr\,d\theta=2\pi\int_1^3z\,dz\int_0^4\frac{r}{\cosh^2r}\,dr$$

so you just have to compute $\int\frac{r}{\cosh^2r}\,dr$. You can rewrite this as $\int\frac{4r}{e^{-r}+e^r}\,dr=\int\frac{4re^{2r}}{(1+e^{2r})^2}\,dr$ and try a substitution.

**Edit:**  Actually the last integral is computed a lot more easily if you are familiar with hyperbolic functions:

$$\int\frac{r}{\cosh^2r}\,dr=\int r\,(\tanh r)'\,dr=r\,\tanh r-\int\tanh r\,dr=r\,\tanh r-\ln(\cosh r)$$

Comment: $8 \pi \tanh(4)$